# Анализ вызова функции в коде

Tags: c++, ооп

Стоит задача проверить правильность вызова функций в некотором файле с++. Я предположил, что вызов функции в коде можно найти, если обнаружить в тексте шаблон типа *имя_функции(параметры)*, то есть грамотнее всего будет искать в тексте первоначально именно скобки. Это можно сделать конструкцией вроде:
"ищем открывающую скобку -> ищем закрывающую скобку -> если до открывающей скобки есть то, что похоже на имя функции и внутри скобок перечисление аргументов -> функция найдена, создаем обьект класса и т.д. и т.п."
Но даный подход не позволяет обрабатыватывать случаи, когда вызов функции происходит в качестве передаваемого параметра к другой функции. Есть ли какой-нибудь более правильный путь для этой задачи?

Comment: Может проще вызвать компилятор и проанализировать результат?

Comment: В глобальном смысле задача - написать лексический анализатор, который проверяет правильность одного конкретного аспекта языка

Comment: Это игрушечаная задача из универа, или вам правда это нужно? Плюсы очень сложно разобрать руками, используйте libclang.

Comment: игрушечная из универа :(

Comment: Если игрушечная, то просто разбирайте текст на лексемы и используя рекурсивный спуск анализируйте. Идентификатор, не являющийся ключевым словом (т.е. не if, for и т.п.) после которого идет скобка -- это вызов функции. Список аргументов разбираете тем же парсером и у вас не возникнет проблем со вложенными вызовами функций.

Comment: Правильное решение этой задачи - это libclang, но там будет в пару строчек (это же по сути кусок одноименного компилятора, парсящий С++ - позвать пару функций, чтобы проверить код на корректность и напечатать ошибки) - такое вряд ли примут в универе? Если у вас такое не одобряют и цель - просто сдать, то на *"не позволяет обрабатыватывать случаи, когда вызов функции происходит в качестве передаваемого параметра"* я бы забил - главное чтобы препод об этом не вспомнил.